# Ordinal Logistic Regression with Polr: Compare multiple treatments

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, polr

Let's say I have information about three stages of cancer (Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3) and three treatment groups.
Now I'd like to compare if the odds ratio for all of these three groups are different.

In theory, I'd do this in R using `polyr(stage ~ treatment)`. But this would only give me the p value for the comparsion of

- treatment group 1 vs treatment group 2
- treatment group 1 vs treatment group 3

But I would like to compare treatment group 2 vs treatment group 3, too.

How can you perform all three comparsions (and get their p-values)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `glht`:

```
library(MASS)
m <- polr(Count ~ Groups)

library(multcomp)
contrasts <- c('GroupsB == 0',
               'GroupsC == 0',
               'GroupsC - GroupsB == 0')
summary(glht(m, linfct=contrasts))
```

Comment: please explain what your snippet is doing

Comment: If you only want a p-value (which means you are setting your sights pretty low IMHO), just get the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test with 2 degrees of freedom for this model, which has a perfect multiplicity adjustment built-in.   Note that you can easily get this from `polr` and even more easily from the R `rms` package's `lrm` and `orm` functions.